# How can I temporarily disable notifications in GNOME 3?

Tags: notification

I want to stop these:

[image]

I need a one liner that can be run from the command line.

I want it to stop *all* notifications, including Spotify and any newly opening apps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to disbale it:

```
sudo mv /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service.disabled
```

to enable again:

```
sudo mv /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service.disabled /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service
```

Comment: No file or directory.